# Is $(\nabla \times \nabla)$ an operator?

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Is $(\nabla \times \nabla)$ an operator?

I am wondering if its possible to compute
\begin{align}
\vec{f} \cdot (\nabla \times \nabla)
\end{align}

Where $f$ is a vector. I would be interested in both cartesian and polar expressions.

Comment: I guess you mean $(\nabla \times \nabla)\cdot \vec{f}$, don't you ? This is not the same.

Comment: What is exactly the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By equality of mixed partials, that is the fact that:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y \partial z}&=\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial z \partial y}\\
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial z \partial x}&=\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x \partial z}\\
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x \partial y}&=\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y \partial x},
\end{align}
$$
where $g$ is some function of $x$, $y$, and $z$, one has the following result for $C^2$ functions:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{f}\cdot\left(\nabla \times \nabla\right) g
&=\vec{f}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z}\\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ \end{vmatrix} g\\
&= \vec{f}\cdot\left(\hat{x} \left(\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y \partial z}-\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial z \partial y}\right) +\hat{y} \left(\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial z \partial x}-\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x \partial z}\right) +\hat{z} \left(\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x \partial y}-\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y \partial x}\right)\right)\\
&=\vec{f}\cdot\vec{0}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
So, this is, as user297767 said, merely a fancy way of writing the zero operator.

---

If this is too similar to user297767's answer I apologize, but being as my edit of their post was rejected for "deviating from the intent of the post", I feel as though it is reasonable for me to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the equality of mixed partials, this is just the zero operator.

Comment: @Leucippus How does this not answer the question?  Apply $\nabla \times \nabla$ or $f\cdot (\nabla \times \nabla)$ to any $C^2$ function on $\Bbb R^3$ and you get zero.  So, assuming you're limiting yourself to twice *continuously* differentiable functions (as opposed to just twice differentiable functions) this operator is just a fancy way of writing the zero operator.

Comment: Edit your answer to include how the operators you have expressed lead to a zero result. Words are fine, but a demonstration is even better.